# When an adjective modifies a noun, can either "look" or "look like" be used?

Tags: grammar

As far as I know, we use "look" with adjectives and "look like" with nouns, but I came across this sentence in [Oxford Dictionaries](http://oald8.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/dictionary/look):

> That looks an interesting book.

Well, I was told that when we want to modify a noun with an adjective, use must use "look like", but this doesn't happen here. I don't know why. Maybe both "look" and "look like" can be used when an adjective modifies a noun.

Comment: Here, "to be" (not "like") has been dropped as it can be easily understood by the reader. It's not a case of adjectives but one of ellipsis.

Comment: In that case, can this sentence be used too? "She looks a princess" instead of "She looks like a princess". In this case I believe it is the same as "She looks to be a princess".

Comment: Yes, it can. It is stilted and archaic, but it does exist.

Answer (score 3):

I did follow your link to the Oxford English Learner's Dictionary, and I did note that the sentence *that looks an interesting book;* however, that is a very odd usage that, to my American ear, sounds incorrect.

*Look* is being used as an [linking verb](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/linking%20verb) in that sentence meaning *to appear* or *to seem.* When used that way, [*look*](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/look) is an [intransitive verb](http://www.writingcentre.uottawa.ca/hypergrammar/trnsintr.html) and therefore should not take an object.

Ordinarily a preposition such as *like* or an infinitive such as *to be* follows linking verbs such as seems, appears, looks, etc.

It should be more like these examples:

```
That looks like an interesting book.
That appears to be an interesting book.
```

If you want to omit the preposition *like,* you would need to change the syntax. With a linking verb, you can use an adjective in the predicate. Note the following example:

```
That book looks interesting.
```

Interesting is still modifying book. It does not need to precede the noun when a linking verb is used. This is called a [predicate adjective](http://grammar.yourdictionary.com/parts-of-speech/adjectives/predicate-adjective.html).

The only other way that I could write that in the same way would be to use the verb *to be,* but that would change the meaning. Take this for example:

```
That *is* an interesting book.
```

That is grammatically correct, but it significantly changes the meaning of the sentence though

Answer (score 2):

*That looks an interesting book* and *That looks like an interesting book* are both grammatical. What you can’t do is drop *like* when there is no adjective. You can say *That looks like a book*, but you can’t say * *That looks a book*. You have to say *That looks **as if** it’s a book*.

Picking up the point in your comment, *She looks to be a princess* doesn’t quite mean *She looks like a princess*. It means *She **seems** to be a princess*. It can also mean *She **wants** to be a princess*.

Comment: I've never heard *to look* used that way without *like* or *to be.* Is this specific to BrE?

Comment: In the sense ‘To have the appearance of being; to seem to the sight’, and construed with a predicative noun or adjective, the OED has supporting citations spanning nearly four centuries. From Dryden: ‘All pale he lies, and looks a lovely Flow'r.’ From Pope: ‘She moves a Goddess, and she looks a Queen!’ From the late nineteenth century: ‘Kitty did not look the lady she was not.’ I would not hesitate to use it now, as in ‘You look a terrible sight’ or ‘She looked a complete mess.’

Comment: The example “that looks a book” does not work, it is too awkward. But in other cases, even forms without adjectives work fine—for example your Pope quote. Or the somewhat common phrase (on both sides of the Atlantic) ‘looking the part’: “Wow, that’s a great outfit you’ve found there. You really look the part!”.

Comment: I don't doubt that that usage has been used historically, but does it still have currency? It sounds archaic to me. Either way, your citations indicate that it is BrE (which is fine). I've only heard that usage in AmE describing people, and even then rarely and colloquially as in *She looks/looked a hot mess.* I wasn't sure which dialect the asker was inquiring about.

Comment: @John Q Public. Not even with a predicative adjective, as in _She looks nice_ or _That looks good_?

Comment: @BarrieEngland I have no problem with that usage when the adjective is a predicate adjective. I'm objecting to the syntax of *that looks an interesting book.* To my American ear it should be *that book looks interesting.*

Comment: @Janus Bahs Jacquet. I’m not sure constructions such as the one in the Pope quote would be much used in the UK now, but we'd use a nonpersonal noun without an adjective. We'd say _She looked a mess_, and I thought Americans might say _She looked a million dollars_.

Comment: @John Q Public. Yet another transatlantic difference then, and one I wasn't aware of.

Comment: Americans would be a lot more likely, I think, to say, “She looked _like_ a million dollars”.

Comment: I hope it isn't a personal idiosyncracy. No speakers of British English around to support me?

Comment: @BarrieEngland Indeed I agree with Janus Bahs Jacquet that the American idiom is *She looked like a millon dollars/bucks.*

Comment: @BarrieEngland Hands Across the Sea, Barrie! I've heard and read plenty of Englishpersons using that construction; I've used it myself (but I was raised by English professors). Over here, though, it's rare--my impression is that it's literary rather than formal, except in fixed phrases like *looks every inch an X* or, on your side of the Atlantic, *looks a right X*.